# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE help required

Tags: mysql, sql, import

Here's my query for loading mysql table using csv file.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE table.csv REPLACE INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\'' LINES TERMINATED BY 'XXX' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

SET date_modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Suppose my CSV contains 500 records with 15 columns. I changed three rows and  terminated them with 'XXX'. I now want to update the mysql table with this file. My primary key is auto-incremented value. When I run this query, all the 500 rows are getting updated with old data and the rows I changed are getting added as new ones. I dont want the new ones. I want my table to be replaced with csv as-is. I tried changing my primary key to non-AI, it still didnt work. Any pointers please?? Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you truncate the table and then import the data file?

Comment: yea that's an option, but users want it this way. It's easy to mark a row change than to delete unchanged rows.You mean this, right?

Comment: I think what @Ander2 means is that you clear the existing table of all its contents, then import the changed file.

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1`.

Comment: @SQLCurious , I emptied the table and tried. But only the changed records (records terminated by XXX) got added to the table since I mentioned LINES TERMINATED clause. If i remove this clause, I cannot update 'date_modified' to only changed records, right?

Answer (score 0):

*I am making some assumptions here.*

1) You dont have the autonumber value in your file.

Since your primary key is not in your file MySQL will not be able to match rows. A autonumber primary key is a artificial key thus it is not part of the data. MySQL adds this artificial primary key when the row is inserted.

Lets assume your file contained some unique identifier lets call it Identification_Number. This number is both in the file and your table uses it as a primary key in this case MySQL will be able to identify the rows from the file and match them to the rows in the table.

While a lot of people will only use autonumbers in a database I always check if there is not a natural key in the data. If I identify one I do some performance testing with this natural key in a table. Then based on the performance metrics of both I then decide on a key.

Hopefully I did not get your question wrong but I suspect this might be the case.

Comment: Both my file and table have auto-incremented value.

Comment: Do the value in the file and database match?

Comment: Yes, the primary key value matches in both file and database.

Comment: Damn well there goes that theory. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I got this working. But there is no LOAD DATA option for this. I filtered the file based on 'XXX' and updated the table based on that.